# Verify font colour with Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I'd like to verify a font colour in Robot Framework.

```
 ${LOCATOR}    //span[@title="mytitle"]
 ${SELECTEDGREEN}=    Get Element Attribute    ${LOCATOR}
```

but I don't see how to pass my desired color attribute to the locator:

## 97B424

Comment: Relevant `HTML` please.

Comment: What does `Get Element Atribute` keyword do?

Comment: The CSS which contains the colour I wish to query is in this format:     .myList .itemSelected, .myList .itemSelected .itemAlternativeMatchText {
    color: #97B424;

Comment: Try `.getCssValue("color")`

Comment: So there isn't a ${SELECTEDGREEN}=    Get Element Attribute    ${LOCATOR}    color type syntax available?

Comment: Note sure how I'd apply the .getCssValue("color") to my script

Answer (score 0):

[Selenium2LibraryExtension](https://github.com/ASKIDA/Selenium2LibraryExtension) has keywords to check an element's text color. Just take into consideration that the library isn't updated to work with the latest version of [SeleniumLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SeleniumLibrary).

You can also possibly check the library's code to see how it works and implement it yourself.